# Total downloads after a period of time

Tags: dropbox, orangedox

I have a software product that's ready to launch and it's totally free. I want to use Orangedox as my hosting service, but I've got two questions.

1. Can I know my overall download count even after one year, not monthly? Does the count reset for every month? (I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced in this.)
2. Does Orangedox (or Dropbox) terminate the link after a certain period of time? Can I keep the same link for several years?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions

1. Yep you can know your overall download count aggregated monthly, the counter does not reset but you will need at least a Pro account to see more than 60 days history
2. Dropbox nor Orangedox doesn't terminate share links, however if you move the files within your Dropbox folders the links will stop working (since they are tied to a file path within Dropbox).

Comment: Feel free to send us an email support@orangedox.com if you have any other specific questions